# Use singleton to encapsule a timer

Tags: c#, singleton

I have a class which initialize a threading.timer. I need to make sure that it will be just one instance of the timer in all the site.
I think i should use singleton for that, I`m right?
The question is, how should i do that? I never implemented Singleton.
Here is my code, so you can understand what i mean..

```
public class start
{
    public start()
    {
        var timer = new Timer(CallBack, null, 0, 60000);
    }
    private void CallBack(object obj)
    {
       //Code
    }
}
```

So, the idea is, when i initialice the class Start, slways use the some timer, and not instance a new one.
Thanks

Comment: What research have you done in terms of finding out how to implement the singleton pattern in C#? There are lots of resources available for that.

Comment: You might be able to find a good example if you would google "Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typically, you would have a private static instance of you class and a static getter. Make your constructor also private. In the getter you check whether the private instance is already created. If no, create and return it, if yes, just return the instance.

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton instance_ = null;

    private Timer timer_;


    public static GetInstance(){
        if (instance_ == null) instance_ = new MySingleton();
        return instance_;
    }

    private MySingleton(){
         timer_ = new Timer(Callback, ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: This implementation will work most of the time, but has some serious issues. You should read John Skeet's article on implementing the Singleton pattern at http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx, and follow his recommendations.

Comment: @JimMischel yes, you're right. this is the simplest version of a singleton, which is not threadsafe. But in many situations this will suffice.